# How to get work range selector with Highcharts with a function?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I don't see the range selector, but I have written that in the code.
I have initialized the chart using variable, like:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Érték'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 20,
            color: '#FFFFFF'
        }]
    },
    //animation: Highcharts.svg,
    boost: {
        seGPUTranslations: true
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'none',
            'stroke-width': 0,
            r: 8,
            style: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            states: {
                hover: {},
                select: {
                    fill: '#039',
                    style: {
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }
                // disabled: { ... }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Prociszenzor'
    },
    series: []
});
```

As you see it doesn't contain any series, I do add it from an another code:

```
chart.addSeries({
    type: 'line',
    name: dataaa.ertekek[i].neve + " " + dataaa.ertekek[i].mertek,
    data: [{
        y: dataaa.ertekek[i].ertek / 100,
        x: time
    }]
});
```

Dataaa is from a JSON file.
I do push this array to the main chart array, and I add points to this using addPoint function. I want to make a rangeselector, but I don't have idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posted no example of what you are expecting I am assuming.

I made the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uc1g8b5/) based on your code.
Note that I did the following changes from what I can see you have posted.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

I am note sure if you are using the highstock library, but if you want a range selctor, you should. See [highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector)

```
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
```

I changed `chart` to be a `stockChart`.

Comment: Hm. I forgot to write enabled:  true, into the code.